# How do I implement/use C++ header files in MATLAB?

Tags: c++, matlab

I have a c++ code for generation of disparity maps as in stereo images sort of thing. The folder contains both .cpp and .h files. I have to implement that code in MATLAB. how would i do?
the code is available in here http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a MEX module, which is a C or C++ shared library that becomes a function inside MATLAB.  The implementation can use just about any C and C++ libraries you want to.